# Elasticsearch "Client only" dependency in Maven

Tags: java, elasticsearch

We need to include a elasticsearch client into a project which itself uses Lucene for other indexing/storage tasks. Including the whole library results in a dependency conflict because the Lucene versions are not the same (ES uses 4.7, we use 4.0).
Is there any "client only" package of elasticsearch or does anybody can think of any other solution?

**Edit:**

The approach to exclude all the lucene packages resulted in the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/lucene/util/Version
    at org.elasticsearch.Version.<clinit>(Version.java:42)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.<init>(TransportClient.java:169)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.<init>(TransportClient.java:125)
    at de.tensquare.wpt.entrysearchindex.ElasticSearchClient.<init>(ElasticSearchClient.java:74)
    at de.tensquare.wpt.entrysearchindex.SearchIndex.<init>(SearchIndex.java:81)
    at de.tensquare.wpt.entrysearchindex.SearchIndex.main(SearchIndex.java:152)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.lucene.util.Version
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

Comment: are you using client in OSGI???

Comment: if you are using the transport client you might be able to get it to work excluding the lucene transitive dependency when importing elasticsearch.

Comment: @BlackPOP: I am not familiar with OSGI. How can it help fix my problem?

Comment: @javanna: I've excluded all lucene specific packages from the elasticsearch dependencies and added the result in the question.

Comment: whats your elasticsearch version and java version???

Comment: @Benjamin that's what I feared... pretty bad as it shows a direct dependency to lucene (its Version class) in the transport client. Do you mind opening an [issue](https://www.github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues) so we can see if we can easily fix it? Otherwise, a solution might be to shade lucene within elasticsearch so that you don't have conflicts anymore, although of course it would be great to have a separate client which we don't have at the moment.

Comment: @BlackPOP ES 1.1.0, java 8

Comment: @javanna Thank you. Here's the issue https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/6170

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently ran into similar issues. We have both solr and elasticsearch in our stack. Using elasticserch transport client, we were ran into lucence snafus. Here is the workaround that helped me. I created a shaded jar that changes how elasticsearch references lucene and carrot search packages.

**EDIT**: I ran into issue from another project, so needed to shade a bit further, updated solution

**elasticsearch wraper project pom**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project .>
    <parent>
        <artifactId>someartifactId</artifactId>
        <groupId>some.group.id</groupId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>someartifactId-elasticsearch</artifactId>
    <name>Some Artifact Elasticsearch</name>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
            <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>attach-sources</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <filters>
                    <filter>
                        <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>META-INF/services/org.apache.lucene.codecs.Codec</exclude>
                            <exclude>META-INF/services/org.apache.lucene.codecs.DocValuesFormat</exclude>
                            <exclude>META-INF/services/org.apache.lucene.codecs.PostingsFormat</exclude>
                            <exclude>META-INF/services/org.apache.lucene.analysis.util.CharFilterFactory</exclude>
                            <exclude>META-INF/services/org.apache.lucene.analysis.util.TokenFilterFactory</exclude>
                            <exclude>META-INF/services/org.apache.lucene.analysis.util.TokenizerFactory</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </filter>
                </filters>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <relocations>
                            <relocation>
                                <pattern>org.</pattern>
                                <shadedPattern>hack.org.</shadedPattern>
                            </relocation>
                            <relocation>
                                <pattern>com.</pattern>
                                <shadedPattern>hack.com.</shadedPattern>
                            </relocation>
                        </relocations>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer
                                implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer" />
                        </transformers>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>

            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

## In src/main/resources/META-INF/services, create shaded filters and codecs that get packaged up

```
hack.org.apache.lucene.analysis.util.CharFilterFactory
hack.org.apache.lucene.analysis.util.TokenFilterFactory
hack.org.apache.lucene.codecs.Codec
hack.org.apache.lucene.codecs.DocValuesFormat
hack.org.apache.lucene.codecs.PostingsFormat
hack.org.apache.lucene.analysis.util.TokenizerFactory
```

Now to use the TransportClient (or any other elastic search class) use package
hack.org.elasticsearch....

Comment: You mentioned your project uses both Solr and Elasticsearch, but the pom file above only contains Elasticsearch. Did you have separate projects for Solr and Elasticsearch?

Comment: Yes, it was a separate project that was bundled in a fat jar if I remeber correctly

Answer (score 0):

Include elasticsearch.1.1.0.jar and lucune.4.7.jar in class path. its enough for transport Client.

HOpe it helps..!